# Hyperledger-Fabric Sample Code - First Network Error - node not found

Tags: amazon-ec2, hyperledger-fabric

I am attempting to build a dev environment on a Ubuntu EC2 instance.  I have loaded the samples, generated certs.  When I run ./byfn.sh up  I get the following verbose output.

```
+ peer channel join -b mychannel.block
+ res=1
+ set +x
2019-06-20 11:25:28.159 UTC [main] InitCmd -> WARN 001 CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL is no longer supported, please use the FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC environment variable
2019-06-20 11:25:28.163 UTC [main] SetOrdererEnv -> WARN 002 CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL is no longer supported, please use the FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC environment variable
Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer0.org1.example.com:7051: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp: lookup peer0.org1.example.com: no such host"
peer0.org1 failed to join the channel, Retry after 3 seconds
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! After 5 attempts, peer0.org1 has failed to join channel 'mychannel'  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========

ERROR !!!! Test failed
```

I have removed the images and re-downloaded.  Cleared the network.  Regenerated the certs.  I think this is a timing issue and stuff has not come up yet.

Comment: I have deleted and redownloaded the docker images.  I also played around with timeout settings.  All to no avail.  Any assistance appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding  `- GODEBUG=netdns=go` in the environment section of peer-base.yaml file.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Where is peer-base.yaml?  I am in the "first-network" directory.   There are multiple yaml files and I'm not sure which one you are referring too.